# Lost files while Cutting and Pasting

Tags: filemanager

This is getting awkward.

Several times it has happened. I cut and paste several files. Some but not all files end up in the new director while the others disappear.

What is up with the file management?

It has happened when moving on disc, between disc and USB and between disc and another computer. I do not believe it ever happened in a Windows environment.

---

I am doing another batch of file transfers. One thing that stands out is that the file transfer or data writing continues after the dialogue box have disappeared. When pressing eject it takes several minutes before the data has truly written and the USB can be unmounted.

Why is it that the dialogue box does not correspond to what is happening in the background? It should represent what is actually happening and not theoretically.

Comment: Do you have a repeatable problem you can describe?  Your question is a bit vague.  Are you moving files to a usb key the not removing the usb key safely, for example?

Comment: It happened both when moving files to a usb stick and when moving files on the network to a Windows computer.